# Netlogo, stats Extension

Tags: statistics, netlogo

I have installed the stat extension for Netlogo to run a written code. The code seems to be ok but I get an internal error message. 
Any idea what the problem is?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cern/jet/stat/Gamma
```

Comment: What version of the stats extension are you using?  It sounds like there may be a mismatch between the extension and colt.jar that is used for evaluating the Gamma function.

Comment: In particular, are you sure that the colt.jar file is in the stats directory with the stats.jar extension?